# phonegap loading php for connection to mysql using eclipse

Tags: php, jquery, android, eclipse, cordova

I'm trying to connect to mysql through jquery $.getJSON, but its not working. I'm using phonegap to try to build an android app while using eclipse. I followed these steps: http://phonegap.com/start#android and I was able to get the initial setup to work. But now I'm trying to access a PHP file so I can connect to mysql.

I have something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
     function onLoad(){
         document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
     }
     function onDeviceReady(){
         $.getJSON("php/connecting.php",function(data){
            $.each(data,function(key,item){
            alert(data.id);
            $(".ui-listview").append('<li>Test</li>');
            });
         });
         return false;
     }
  </script>
```

in the body

```
<body onload="onLoad();">

<div data-role="page" id='buyDrink'>
<div data-role="content"> 

  <ul data-role="listview" class="ui-listview">
  </ul>

</div>
</div>

</body>
```

I do have my php file in `assets/php/connecting.php` my index.html file is in `assets/www`

Comment: @xDragonZ how would I gain access to my php?

Comment: Run the PHP on a server and use the $.getJSON to get the data from the server.

Comment: @Devgeeks do you mean have something like `$.getJSON("http://www.msite.com/php/connecting.php",function(data){..` ?

Comment: Yes, I believe that's what he means. Android does not know how to execute PHP, so you'll have to host it on a server somewhere and then make requests to it in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you have to connect it to an actual server to get it right!